# Pandas how to drop a level and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

How do I drop a level on the columns and also remove all columns except "City" and "geometry"

```
             AREA  AA5000  HOLD  LEVEL  TYPE   ID  TAZCE10_N                                           geometry
City                                                                                                                    
Detroit  0.120861     2.0     1.0       5.0       0.0  1.0     1101.0  (POLYGON ((-83.47904699999999 41.706103, -83.4...
Austin        NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN        NaN  (POLYGON ((-97.577304 29.610979, -97.580744999...
```

so that it looks like this:

```
City      geometry                                                                                                                
Detroit  (POLYGON ((-83.47904699999999 41.706103, -83.4...
Austin   (POLYGON ((-97.577304 29.610979, -97.580744999...
```

Technically this is a geopandas df that I temporarily convert to normal df because geopandas doesn't have droplevel(). I've tried the statements below but they don't work and droplevel throws an error "AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'droplevel'.

```
    df.columns = [c[-1] for c in df.columns]
    df.reset_index()
    df.columns.droplevel()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `dropna` with `thresh`

```
df=df.dropna(axis=1,thresh=len(df)).reset_index()
```

Comment: That's pretty close, it drops all the columns but the multilevel is still a problem.  Also the NaN's aren't relevant, I just need to drop all columns except City and geometry regardless

Comment: @Calculus adding reset_index at the end, base on my knowledge, that is index name , not multiple index

Comment: Yea the reset_index works, although I don't understand why that works only after the dropna statement, doing it before doesn't fix the mutlilevel problem. Anyways, Thanks.

Comment: @Calculus ah, yw :-) , i think you just need to assign it back